# Unity: Move Sprite Up and Down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

While I know my way round C# I am new to using it in game development and Unity. I am wanting to make a ball bounce up and down. I can easily get the ball to move left and right but when change my code from a 'roll' to a 'bounce' I get the below result:(The ball goes diagonally not up and down) [image]

but what I want:

[image]

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (moveDown) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x);
        } else {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (1f, 1f, 1f);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (-speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x);
        }
    }
```

I'm sure the answer must be something simple but after a long day my brain has gone to mush. Can anyone advise?

Ps the working left to right code goes something like this:

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-1f, 1f, 1f);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);
```

Comment: `var vel = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity; vel.y *= -1; GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = vel;`

Comment: This seems close to what I need but isn't work perfect. The ball slowly decedents but bumps up a tiny bit every second making it look like it is vibrating. I'll need to investigate what is happening.

Comment: Only call the code when the ball hits the top or the bottom, not on each frame...

Comment: Derp my bad, as I said long day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Vector2 has two components; X and Y.  The "X" component of the velocity represents the object's horizontal speed (left/right).  The "Y" component of the velocity represents the object's vertical speed (up/down).

To move *straight* up and down, the "X" component of the velocity must be 'Zero' (0), otherwise the object will continue to move horizontally as well as vertically, resulting in a diagonal.

When calling the constructor for Vector2, you pass in two parameters; the first parameter is the "X" value, and the second component is the "Y" value.  In your example code, you pass a non-zero value in the first (X) parameter, resulting in diagonal movement.

Comment: When I try this: 

transform.localScale = new Vector2 ( 0, 1f);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x);

My ball just disappears

Comment: @Phil3992 thats because you are adjusting the scale of the ball to 0...  Essentially a scale of 1 with a ball that is 32x32 pixels is still 32x32 pixels so changing the x scale to 0 makes the ball 0x32 (size * scale), so if the ball has no size or units it wont be visible and if you have a collider on the ball you prolly also have a warning complaining about this.

Answer (score -1):

You can freeze the x position if that helps.

[image]

Comment: that's not an answer, it's a comment.